# Un-Disable submit button if toggles checked ionic 3 angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2, toggle

A form that I am working on includes two toggles, which, when checked, will allow the user to submit the form. However, while I am able to disable the button, and the current logic enables the button if either toggle is checked, I haven't been able to enable the button ONLY if both toggles are checked.

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label style="font-size:14px">I am over 13 years of age</ion-label>
    <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="age" checked="false" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></ion-toggle>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item >
    <ion-label style="font-size:14px" class="line-break">I agree to the <a (click)="openModal('privacy')">Privacy Policy</a> & <a (click)="openModal('terms')">Terms</a></ion-label>
    <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="termsprivacy" checked="false" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></ion-toggle>
  </ion-item>

  <button [(disabled)]="termsprivacy && age" ion-button block type="submit">
    Create an Account
  </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this works, note `[(disabled)]="!termsprivacy || !age"`:

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label style="font-size:14px">I am over 13 years of age</ion-label>
    <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="age" checked="false" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></ion-toggle>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item >
    <ion-label style="font-size:14px" class="line-break">I agree to the <a (click)="openModal('privacy')">Privacy Policy</a> & <a (click)="openModal('terms')">Terms</a></ion-label>
    <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="termsprivacy" checked="false" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></ion-toggle>
  </ion-item>

  <button [(disabled)]="!termsprivacy || !age" ion-button block type="submit">
    Create an Account
  </button>
```

Comment: Since disabled is an attribute, it should work with just `[disabled]="..."` instead of `[(disabled)]="..."`

Answer (score 1):

After processing your submission, you need to set these variables, else once you have set them, they will always be set to true and the button will always be disabled.

termsprivacy == false && age == false